# Angular: filtering an ng-repeat with an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to filter an ng-repeat by an array of items. I have tried something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filteredItems">
```

Where `filteredItems` is an array containing a subset of `items`. This doesn't seem to work. Is there another way this can work?

Comment: Why the downvote? Legitimate question, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter the second param(expression) should be string or object or function, this case use function better

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: function(item){ return in_array(item,filteredItems);}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works, please update your code with

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems.items | filter: filteredItems.search">
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work as filteredItems isn't an array to begin with, only items is.